# Can't sort values after aggregation using Pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, aggregate-functions

I have the following dataframe:

```
df[['ID','Team']].groupby(['Team']).agg([('total','count')]).reset_index("total").sort_values("count")
```

I basically, need to count the number of IDs by Team and then sort by the total number of IDs.

The aggregation part it's good and it gives me the expected result. But when I try the sort part I got this:

```
KeyError: 'Requested level (total) does not match index name (Team)'
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try this df[['ID','Team']].groupby(['Team']).agg([('total','count')]).reset_index().sort_values("count")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use names aggregation for specify new columns names in aggregate function, remove `total` from [`DataFrame.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'ID':list('abcdef'),
        'Team':list('aaabcb')
})

df = df.groupby('Team').agg(count=('ID','count')).reset_index().sort_values("count") 
print (df)
  Team  count
2    c      1
1    b      2
0    a      3
```

Your solution should be changed by specify column after `groupby` for processing, then specify new column name with aggregate function in tuple and last also remove `total` from `reset_index`:

```
df = df.groupby('Team')['ID'].agg([('count','count')]).reset_index().sort_values("count")
print (df)
  Team  count
2    c      1
1    b      2
0    a      3
```